# I need help adding a constructor to this class so i can add the menubar to my main class

Tags: java

this is the menubar class if this is put directly into the main class it works however in its own class it does not because there is no constructor and im having difficulty doing it  i understand the importance of constructors but cant seem to get my head around how to add it to this class

```
public class MenuBar extends mainClass {

   JFrame frame = new JFrame("Assingment");
   JMenuBar menuBar;
   JMenu menu, submenu;
   JMenuItem menuItem;
   JPopupMenu popup;

   {
      menuBar = new JMenuBar();
      menu = new JMenu("File");
      menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
      menu.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("File Menu");
      menuBar.add(menu);

      menuItem = new JMenuItem("Load");
      menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
      menu.add(menuItem);

      menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                  switch (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame)) {
                    case JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION:
                        break; 
                  }
               }
      });


      menuItem = new JMenuItem("Save", KeyEvent.VK_T);
      menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_2, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
      menuItem.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("Save");
      menu.add(menuItem);

      menuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit",KeyEvent.VK_T);
      menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_3, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
      menuItem.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("Exit");
      menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
               System.exit(0);
          }
      });

      menu.add(menuItem);
      menu = new JMenu("Help");
      menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
      menu.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("Help Menu");
      menuBar.add(menu);

      frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
      frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

First class--

```
 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel {

private final static Color BACKGROUND_COL = Color.DARK_GRAY;


private BufferedImage image;

public void drawLine(Color color, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

    g.setColor(color);

    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}


public void clear() {

    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

    g.setColor(BACKGROUND_COL);

    g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(),  image.getHeight());
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    // render the image on the panel.
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}





GraphicsPanel() {

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));

    image = new BufferedImage(800, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    // Set max size of the panel, so that is matches the max size of the image.
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));

    clear();
}



  }
```

Mainclass--

```
public class mainClass extends GraphicsPanel  {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Assingment");
   mainClass GraphPan = new mainClass();
   MenuBar mnuBar=new MenuBar();
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   frame.setContentPane(GraphPan);
   frame.pack();
   frame.setVisible(true);
}


}
```

Comment: should this create a whole window with menubar if you call the constructor?

Comment: yes it brings up a small window with the menubar @XtremeBaumer

Comment: why do you extend the mainClass?

Comment: i thought i needed to do that in order to use the Jmenu in a seprerate class?

Comment: no you don't need to do it. as i know you only extend a class to get its methods in your class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class TestGui extends JFrame {
    public TestGui() {
        super();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(true);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        createMenu(this.getContentPane());
        createPanel(this.getContentPane());
        this.pack();
        this.setPreferredSize(this.getSize());
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

private void createMenu(Container pane) {


    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("Datei");
    menuBar.add(menu);
    JMenuItem menuItemClose = new JMenuItem("Schließen");
    JMenuItem menuItemEdit = new JMenuItem("Bearbeiten");
    JMenuItem menuItemUndo = new JMenuItem("Rückgängig");

    menuItemEdit.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_E, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    menuItemEdit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });
    menuItemClose.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F4, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
    menuItemClose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dispose();
        }
    });
    JMenuItem menuItemAdd = new JMenuItem("Einfügen");
    menuItemAdd.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    menuItemAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }

    });

    menuItemUndo.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    menuItemUndo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }

    });
    menu.add(menuItemAdd);
    menu.add(menuItemEdit);
    menu.add(menuItemUndo);
    menu.add(menuItemClose);
    menuBar.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 21));


    pane.add(menuBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
}
private void createPanel(Container contentPane) {
    JPanel g = new JPanel();
    g.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));

    image = new BufferedImage(800, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    // Set max size of the panel, so that is matches the max size of the
    // image.
    g.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));

    clear();
    add(g);
}

private final static Color BACKGROUND_COL = Color.DARK_GRAY;

private BufferedImage image;

public void drawLine(Color color, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

    g.setColor(color);

    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}

public void clear() {

    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

    g.setColor(BACKGROUND_COL);

    g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    // render the image on the panel.
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}

}
```

this code will create a window with a menubar in the top left corner and a dark grey jpanel. the only problem is that the menubar is **behind** the jpanel, but if you hit the menu with your courser, you will see it

Comment: im confused as to how i would use MenuBar c=new MenuBar();

Comment: write that line in the main method of your starter class

Comment: in the main class?

Comment: i already have a popup which ive sized but this adds another popup how do i fix that?

Comment: i will need your full code of all the classes to help you

Comment: as i understand it you want the menubar to be part of the JFrame you create in mainClass. am i right?

Comment: when i run this code it doesn't seem to bring the menubar up on the popup

Comment: in which popup?

Comment: the dark grey popup which is meant to have the menubar

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve? once the program starts there should be a window with the menubar and once you click the item of the menubar, a new window should pop up?

Comment: no the grey popup window should have the menubar on it with all the functionality of the menu, no new popus should open

Comment: so in the existing window I had created I want the menubar to be visible in there

Comment: well i have totally no clue why it isn't working. i even copied code from other project with a working JMenuBar but that isn't working either

Comment: @A.hussain i updated my answer once again. its not the best solution probably but it has what you want with a minor bug